# app with wikitude, change the view

Tags: ios, view, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am an IOS programmer and added this SDK to my application which has a tab bar that shows a view with a button showing the wikitude camera, I would like to know how I could go back to my last view from de wikitude camera.
I have tried to do it removing the view from wikitude from the window, which actually works but unfortunatelly, when i want to go back to the wikitude view, the application crashes. Hopefully you can help me find out how to solve this problem. Best regrads.

Answer (score 0):

For showing/hiding the AR view the best option is to use the accoring show and hide methods of the WikitudeARViewController.